# Apply loop cut to different parts at once?

Tags: modeling, edges

**How to loop cut all of this selected parts to bottom. When i try to loop cut it only apply to one part.**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by loopcut the selected parts?

Comment: I mean every propeller. I want to add loop cut under the selected (yellow colored) places.

Comment: You can't add them automatically to all the blades, that's why it's generally better to model this kind of object with, for example, an Array modifier (in Object Offset mode) that will allow you to kind of instance 6 times the same mesh

Answer (score 3):

First, select the tip of each propeller.

Then increase the selection by hiting CTRL and +

Then press I, and O for outset

Make sure you enable edge rail in the subpannel

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't add them automatically to all the blades, that's why it's generally better to model this kind of object with, for example, an *Array* modifier (in *Object Offset* mode) that will allow you to kind of instance 6 times the same mesh.

That said you can select the edges and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (*Offset Edge Slide*), which will create parallel edges, then remove the extra edges:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start with a shape like this:

[image: 1]

- Switch to Edge selection mode (1 in the screenshot) and select the edge rings you want to subdivide. Edge ring selection can be done by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and left clicking (or right click if you use right click select) the edges marked 2, 3, 4, and 5 in the screenshot below. In your case, you have two more edges to click.

[image: 2]

- Run `Edge > Subdivide` and customize the subdivisions in the *Adjust Last Operation* panel.

[image: 3]

Comment: The only problem with this solution compared to the other answers is you have no ability to edge slide the loop cuts closer or further from the middle simultaneously.

Comment: I agree. If edge sliding is important, I think Alex's answer is the best. I'll vote it up. It won't be the easiest for adding multiple evenly-spaced loops, though. I agree with moonboots that using an Array modifier would be the best option for working with the provided shape.